# Error during template rendering in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to submit this form to my view:

**in pcq_select.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'pcq_list' product_id %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<label>Select the Product:
<select name="product_id">
    {% for entry in products %}
        <option value="{{ entry.id }}">{{ entry.productname }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go"></label>
</form>
```

**in views.py**

```
def pcq_select(request, template_name='maps/pcq/pcq_select.html'):
    product = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, template_name, {'products': product})


def pcq_list(request, product_id="1"):
    pcq = Pcq.objects.filter(product_id=product_id)
    data = {}
    data['object_list'] = pcq
    return render(request, 'maps/pcq/pcq_list.html', data)
```

**in urls.py**

```
url(r'^pcq/list/(\d+)/$', views.pcq_list, name='pcq_list'),
```

I get the following error:

> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
> Exception Value: Reverse for 'pcq_list' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['maps/pcq/list/(\d+)/$']
>
> Error during template rendering
>
> In template E:\SampleSite\templates\maps\pcq\pcq_select.html, error at line 1

But when I replace the **product_id** in the action url with a number (example 1), the whole thing works good. Kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is something like this:

```
{% for p in products %} <!-- Let's assume there are several products ... -->
    ...
    <form action="{% url 'pcq_list' product_id=p.pk %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Then, you have to specify in your urls.py that the url is waiting for an id this way:

```
url(r'^pcq/list/(?P<product_id>\d+)$', views.pcq_list, name='pcq_list')
```

You can not write `product_id` as is, since the template does not know this variable.

Comment: Nice. Your code is what I expected. Did you try the solution I wrote?

Comment: I enclosed the complete form with the for tag. Replaced entry with p. I get the same error message as I had posted.

Comment: I guess this is because the urls.py have to specify the ID (see my updated post)

Comment: YES! The Url change and product_id=p.pk solved the problem. Thanks a lot David!

Comment: Thank you, I have been stuck on similar kind of problem for 2 days now, I was following django tutorial in which question.id was passed in form action whose value is available to the form. In my case, value was not available directly and thus it was giving me rendering error. Now I have extracted the value and is passing to next html page easily, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your view, but it looks like you are not passing anything called `product_id` to the template.

Answer (score -1):

Are you passing a product to the template? If so, change your original `product_id` to `product.id`.

I.e.:

```
<form action="{% url 'pcq_list' product.id %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
```

Comment: I tried but getting an error message: Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'

Comment: Could you post your `views.py`?

Comment: I have added the views.py